# 'tail -f' doesn't give single lines when piped through grep'

Tags: bash

I am launching a website, and I wanted to setup a Bash one-liner so when someone hits the site it would make a beep using the internal buzzer.

So far it's working using the following.

```
tail -f access_log | while read x ; do echo -ne '\007' $x '\n' ; done
```

Tail follows the access_log and dumps to STDOUT, get STDOUT line at a time, echo the line with '\007' "internal beep hex code", and done...

This works like a beauty... Every hit shows the line from the log and beeps... However, it got annoying very quickly, so ideally I wanted to filter the `tail -f /access/log` before it's piped into the `while` so that read only gets lines I care about. I was thinking `grep "/index.php"` would be a good indication of visitors...

This is where the issue is...

I can do...

```
tail -f access_log | while read x ; do echo -ne '\007' $x '\n' ; done
```

beeps on everything
and i can do...

```
tail -f access_log | grep "/index.php"
```

and pages are shown with no beep, but when i do

```
tail -f access_log | grep "/index.php" | while read x ; do echo -ne '\007' $x '\n' ; done
```

Nothing happens, no line from log, no beep.

I think the grep is messing it up somewhere, but I can't figure out where.
I'd love it to be a one liner, and I know it should really be done in a script and would be easier, but it doesn't explain why the above, which I think should work, isn't.

Comment: can you provide some sample log code for us to look at and mess around with?

Comment: unfortunately not...its riddled with sensitive information... you can use any access_log and just pick one url to grep for.

Comment: its quite a nice feature, the sound (mixture of beeps) from a single web page load can produce about 20-30 beeps (lines in log)... the beep means you can instantly tell at what point the files are being served...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Grep's output is buffered when it's used in a pipe. Use `--line-buffered` to force it to use line buffering so it outputs lines immediately.

```
tail -f access_log | grep --line-buffered "/index.php" | while read x ; do echo -ne '\007' $x '\n' ; done
```

You could also combine the `grep` and `while` loop into a single `awk` call:

```
tail -f access_log | awk '/\/index.php/ { print "\007" $0 }'
```

Comment: now your showing off... will do... never got in awk, but seams to get me out of trouble a lot, maybe time to give the man page a good read over... thank you once again....

Comment: I often use `tail -f access.log | sed -une "s@/index.php@&\o7@p"` simple, quick and efficient! (or `path='/index.php';tail -f access.log | sed -une "s@${path}@&\o7@p"`) See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74183642/1765658)

Answer (score 7):

Grep buffers output when standard output is not a terminal.  You need to pass the `--line-buffered` switch to grep to force it to flush standard output whenever it writes a line.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `sed -u` for *unbuffered*:

Lighter than `awk` and `grep`, using `sed` could be simple, quick and efficient:

```
tail -f access.log | sed -une "s@/index.php@&\o7@p"
```

`sed` will replace *`/index.php`* by ***found string*** `&` plus ***beep***: `\o7`, then print lines where something was replaced. With `-u`, sed will read lines by lines, unbuffered.

```
path='/index.php'
tail -f access.log | sed -une "s@${path}@&\o7@p"
```